# Multivariate exponential integral

Tags: integration

I need to compute the integral
\begin{equation}
I=\int_{a_1}^{b_1} \int_{a_2}^{b_2} \exp\left(c_1x_1+c_2x_2+d_{11}x_1^2+d_{22}x_2^2+d_{12}x_1x_2\right)dx_2 dx_1
\end{equation}
for $x_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$, but $c_{i}, d_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}$.
This can be written in more compact form as
\begin{equation}
I=\int_{a_1}^{b_1} \int_{a_2}^{b_2} \exp(c^T x + x^TDx)dx_2 dx_1
\end{equation}
for real $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, but complex $c \in \mathbb{C}^{2}, D \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$.

The usual apprach is to assume that $D$ can be decomposed.
Can this integral be evaluated explicitly without this assumption?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Chris T.